# ruby on rails render partial inside a json array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, partial

I am trying to render a partial for the ajax request but i can't find how to do it using Ruby on Rails...

here what my array variable

```
@return = { :error => false, :response => "Added", :partial => ... }

render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )
```

where `...` is where the partial(html) should be...

the method name is add_item, its controller is items and i have created an add_item.html.erb file inside the items folder which has the HTML i want to pass to the array and use jQuery to add it to the DOM

i guess this could be done using

```
render :partial => "partial", :object => @object
```

but how can i add this into the array above?

Comment: `render` returns the html, right? Have you tried `{ :error => false, :response => "Added", :partial => render(:partial => "partial", :object => @object) }` ?

Comment: @Robin i am getting an error `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
@return = { :error => false, :response => "Added", :partial => render_to_string(:partial => "partial/path", :object => @object) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do what I think you're trying to do is to fire an ajax message at `add_item`, and then in `add_item` have:

```
def add_item
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and make an `add_item.js.erb` with the jQuery contents:

```
$('#div-for-code').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "mypartial") %>');
```

not sure that it's the best way but it's worked for me.